# Deadlock using Aggregator + Redis

Tags: java, multithreading, redis, spring-integration, aggregator

This post is related to this one

[Spring integration deadlock using Aggregator + MessageStoreReaper + Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24366813/spring-integration-deadlock-using-aggregator-messagestorereaper-redis)

but this message is too long to post. I continue with the original post

I upgraded to to the latest Java 7 build 1.7.0_60-b19 but the problem is still there.

I made another thread dump and found the same issue: all DefaultMessageListenerContainers (count 20) are locked by the taskScheduler (entityScheduler-3) in the AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler lock invocation.

Here's the scheduler and aggregator config:

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="entityScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="entityReaperBean" method="run" fixed-rate="${entity.aggregator.timeout}" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>

<bean id="entityReaperBean" class="org.springframework.integration.store.MessageGroupStoreReaper">
    <property name="messageGroupStore" ref="entityAggregatorRedisMessageStore" />
    <property name="timeout" value="${entity.aggregator.reaper.timeout}" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityAggregatorRedisMessageStore"
    class="org.springframework.integration.redis.store.RedisMessageStore">
    <constructor-arg ref="entityRedisConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<int:aggregator id="entityAggregator" send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"
        release-strategy-expression="size() >= ${transactions-receiver.batch_size}" correlation-strategy-expression="payload.entityCode"
        expire-groups-upon-completion="true" message-store="entityAggregatorRedisMessageStore" />
```

Here's the thread dump section:

```
"entityScheduler-3" - Thread t@188
 java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
 at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 - parking to wait for <545079d6> (a    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1085)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:807)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Locked ownable synchronizers:
 - locked <66d9180c> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)

"DefaultMessageListenerContainer-5" - Thread t@48
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- waiting to lock <66d9180c> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync) owned by "entityScheduler-3" t@188
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:834)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:894)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1221)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly(ReentrantLock.java:340)
at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:223)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor81.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.integration.monitor.SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.handleMessage(SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.java:106)
at org.springframework.integration.monitor.SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.invoke(SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.java:86)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:148)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:171)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor81.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.integration.monitor.SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.handleMessage(SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.java:106)
at org.springframework.integration.monitor.SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.invoke(SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.java:86)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:148)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:171)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor81.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.integration.monitor.SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.handleMessage(SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.java:106)
at org.springframework.integration.monitor.SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.invoke(SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.java:86)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:148)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:171)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor81.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.integration.monitor.SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.handleMessage(SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.java:106)
at org.springframework.integration.monitor.SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.invoke(SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.java:86)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:131)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor81.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.integration.monitor.SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.handleMessage(SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.java:106)
at org.springframework.integration.monitor.SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.invoke(SimpleMessageHandlerMetrics.java:86)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
at org.springframework.integration.jms.SubscribableJmsChannel$DispatchingMessageListener.onMessage(SubscribableJmsChannel.java:148)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:562)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:500)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:468)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1103)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1095)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:992)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

 Locked ownable synchronizers:
  - None
```

Is it possible that for some reason the handleMessageInternal method of the AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler doesn't unlock? I use a Redis message store and see that the MsgStoreReaper also uses a lock. Could that be an issue?

thank you very much for your help here!
Regards
Guzman

**UPDATE:**

I found this messages in the log:

```
 2014-07-23 22:47:26,967 ERROR TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler:95 - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
 2014-07-23 22:47:26,968 ERROR RedisMessageStore:122 - Exception in expiry callback
 2014-07-23 22:47:26,971 ERROR TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler:95 - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
```

but no exception nor stacktrace. Does the TaskUtils error says something to you?

Comment: Forgot to say, I'm using SI v3.0.1

Comment: Hi guys! I've been reading SIv4.x docs and found that a RedisLockRegistry was added. As far as I can see, this Lock may solve this problem. Reaper and Aggregator must use this RedisLockRegistry to avoid locks, am I right?

Comment: This is strange; I don't see any opportunity for the lock to be left locked; the `RedisLockRegistry` won't help - that's for when using multiple application instances and a shared group store.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out one more time! It's really an issue within our code: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3483

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I do see one place...

```
        finally {
            if (removeGroup) {
                this.remove(group);
            }
            lock.unlock();
        }
```

...if the message store throws an exception during the remove, we would skip the unlock - do you see anything in the log?

Comment: I don't see any but I try updating to SI-4.1-snapshot. One more doubt, where are SI-4.1 xsd? Could you please send me the url? thanks!

Comment: We backported the fix to 4.0.x and 3.0.x so it's in 3.0.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. We don't publish the schema until it's released; you can find it int the jar, or on github.

Comment: excelente Gary, thank you very much! I'll try it from local jar

Comment: Gary, one question, isn't the deadlock produced by the Reaper as other threads are waiting for them to work?

Comment: Only if the message store throws an exception while the group is removed.

Comment: Hi Gary, I don't see any application specific exception, can I enable an specific log of SI have more information? maybe the Reaper?

Comment: No; if that removal throws an exception you will see a couple of logs under ERROR level (I just tested it with a dummy exception). Are you still seeing deadlocks - even with the snapshot? - we can't find anywhere in the code (aside from this) where the deadlock could occur.

Comment: We didn't had this issue again but is too soon to confirm it worked

Comment: I added new info in the original post. Any idea about why the exception is not printed?

Comment: The second log should include the exception - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/3.0.x/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/store/AbstractMessageGroupStore.java#L122

Comment: thanks Gary for the answer! It's strange that no exception is printed. I think that the fix resolved the initial error but now I'm trying to understand why the exception in the expiry callback occurs. Continue searching