# Aggregator doesn't release messages from redis message store

Tags: spring-integration

He are using an aggregator with redis and found some messages aren't cleaned from redis. We query the redis message store using SI classes and found that no messages where found but I query redis from the command line and there are still messages there.

this is my simple test to query redis messages where group size is zero:

```
  @Autowired
  private RedisMessageStore loyaltyAggregatorRedisMessageStore;

  @Test
  public void testMessageStoreGroups() {
    MessageGroup group = loyaltyAggregatorRedisMessageStore.getMessageGroup("MESSAGE_GROUP_true");
    System.out.println(group.size());
}
```

but when I query Redis, I have this output:

```
1) "MESSAGE_8fdf96b5-ea0e-45a5-a8db-2b245fc909aa"
...
105) "MESSAGE_2772c17f-539c-c63e-1072-a5e46bb8f13d"
106) "MESSAGE_e42960e9-1801-5376-bbbc-897ad724e0ba"
107) "MESSAGE_a23c9e65-8b0e-4ee4-a3b3-4f90bcd88851"
108) "MESSAGE_1558ec12-a1dc-1afd-c8ea-d8f79ccdbb21"
109) "MESSAGE_GROUP_true"
110) "MESSAGE_a123b075-3f17-4140-d9c3-115295330b6a"
111) "MESSAGE_ba07d76f-641e-7d38-d942-cdccd4b6aa0e"
112) "MESSAGE_fe77a8aa-e273-d202-2c3f-6be7a7376153"
113) "MESSAGE_d89872b0-9b7f-5a94-24a4-62c577b04d37"
114) "MESSAGE_cf935ae2-5813-5636-79ef-4381e0da2982"
115) "MESSAGE_8435ce3f-8b89-6223-1713-72e221382cdd"
116) "MESSAGE_e27daf70-795b-b4db-a262-e94450b88d41"
117) "MESSAGE_a06ad5a9-fafb-b882-747a-31b62cd13425"
118) "MESSAGE_04fe2ae4-9bde-91e8-f136-39f7e8d225f7"
119) "MESSAGE_a13db3bb-246a-3f1a-ed08-1431be324766"
120) "MESSAGE_8423e0fd-0eda-5dcc-3fd9-7b428689c02e"

and more
```

any idea of what could cause this issue?

thanks in advance
Guzman

Answer (score 1):

Show, please how you query Redis directly.

BTW `RedisMessageStore` does it like this:

`AbstractKeyValueMessageStore`:

```
Object mgm = this.doRetrieve(MESSAGE_GROUP_KEY_PREFIX + groupId);
```

Where `MESSAGE_GROUP_KEY_PREFIX` is `MESSAGE_GROUP_`.
So, looks like you overdid quering it like this `"MESSAGE_GROUP_true"`.

There is something wrong in the other place.

If messages would remain in Redis our test servers would fall already for a long time ago...

Comment: Hi Artem! my mistake in the code. I change it and now the following error occurs: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Messages are not available, fetch the entire group. I looked up the MessageGroupMetadata and it has the following data: complete = true,
hasMessages = false, messages:[0aea96aa-da95-fd81-3431-13abebc13ecb, ..., 2772c17f-539c-c63e-1072-a5e46bb8f13d, ..., e42960e9-1801-5376-bbbc-897ad724e0ba, ...,  1558ec12-a1dc-1afd-c8ea-d8f79ccdbb21, ..., 53041154-4b57-bd5a-f169-57d2305e7ff2]. Is correct that the hasMessage attribute is false and the message list is not empty?

Comment: forgot to say, I used the redis command 'keys *' to list the messages

Comment: Hi guys! any idea about this? is correct to have hasMessages = false and a list of messages with elements? thanks again

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Which version of SI do you use? Would you mind to upgrade to the latest? http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/

Comment: I don't see in the current code how `MessageGroupMetadata` may get `false` for the `hasMessages`. Only `true` from the constructor

Comment: Hi Arthem! no problem for the delay :) This problem occured while I was using SIv3.0.3. After an issue with a deadlock+aggregator, I updated to SIv4.0.4. I searched the code and also could not find where can be set to false, but when I make that simple query to the redis message store, does values are return and the following message: "Messages are not available, fetch the entire group." What does this message means? Could this problem be related to this other issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24937398/deadlock-using-aggregator-redis?

Comment: Do you mean this query `loyaltyAggregatorRedisMessageStore.getMessageGroup("MESSAGE_GROUP_true")`? This wrong query? And exactly after has aggregator finished its work alredy?

Comment: Sorry Arthem, I wrote quickly and the sentence made no sense. I made this query loyaltyAggregatorRedisMessageStore.getMessageGroup("true") and the following error ocurrs: "Messages are not available, fetch the entire group.". When I run it in debug mode and watch inside the MessageGroupMetadata object from the AbstractKeyValueMessageStore .buildMessageGroup method, I see this values: complete=true and hasMessages=false, messages=[0aea96aa-da95-fd81-3431-13abebc13ecb, ..., 2772c17f-539c-c63e-1072-a5e46bb8f13d...]. As you can see, messages are in the list but the group has size 0. Any idea?

Comment: Well, looks like it is really a bug. Feel free to raise a JIRA issue (https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT). As a workaround you have to use `expire-groups-upon-completion="true"` for the `<aggregator>`. I don't see yet, what's going on, but `hasMessages` doesn't work correctly. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much Arthem! Unfortunately, expire-groups-upon-completition is already true :S We updated SI to version 4, so we'll wait to see if it happens again. I'll tell you in a few weeks. Thanks for your time! Regards